# Link to a page with iFrame to load different PDF files

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

I'm currently working on a project that has a slight complexity to it, and I'm not completely certain on how to approach this.  I can load PDF's in an iFrame no problem, but the issue we have is as follows:

We have a landing page with links to PDF articles.  We would like to create a second page, with the header and navigation of the landing page, but include some type of iFrame or viewer to allow  a user to click any given PDF link, and have that document load in the viewer or iFrame of the second page.

Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You would have to use Javascript in order to do this. I don't really know how to display the header in a different IFrame, but I do know that you can change the location of an IFrame like this: `<div align="center">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('google').src='http://www.google.com/'">Click Here To Load Google</button>

</div>

  <div align="center">
    <iframe id="google" style="WIDTH: 915px; HEIGHT: 515px" border="" src="about:blank" alt="" scrolling="no">
    <p>iframes are not supported</p></iframe>
  </div>
`

Answer (score 0):

Use shadowbox for that. The site is shadowbox.js

It's easy to install, just follow the simple instructions.

on your landing page you need link

```
<a href="second_page.html#myPDF">PDF</a>
```

on your second page another shadowbox style link

```
<a href="myPDF.pdf" rel="shadowbox" id="myPDF">PDF</a>
```

Don't forget to fix the paths.